# Filtering object containing objects from another table using linq c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have what seems like a simple problem, but can't wrap my head around it.

I have two tables, one contains questions, one responses. These are mapped together such that one question has many allowedResponses. EntityFramework handles this mapping very nicely, so when I call the controller to GetQuestions, I get back a lovely set of questions wach containing their pertinent responses.

We recently expanded the system to include two user groups - A and B in this example. Some questions and some responses are only valid for certain groups. So each question has a showToA showToB property - this works fine using a simple linq.where query. However I cannot figure out how to call getQuestions with the parameter showToGroupA and have it return the questions AND responses ONLY pertinent to the specified group.

I essentially want to be able to get all the relevant questions, and strip out any irrelevant responses.

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
 public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int QID { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AllowedResponses> AllowedResponse { get; set; }

    public int PrimaryOrderNo{ get; set; }
    public int SecondaryOrderNo{ get; set; }
    public bool ShowToGroupA{ get; set; }
    public bool ShowToGroupB{ get; set; }
}

//Model of allowed responses to questions
public class AllowedResponses
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int QID { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public int ResponseID { get; set; }
    public bool ShowToGroupA { get; set; }
    public bool ShowToGroupB { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment I simply return a list of questions, sorted by the appropriate order, and filtered by whether or not the question should be displayed to the group - NOT filtering the AllowedResponses.

```
List<Questions> Questions = _repo.GetQuestions();
        Questions = Questions.OrderBy(x => x.GroupAOrderNo).ToList();
        List<Questions> QuestionsFiltered;
        if (GroupAorB == "A")
        {
            QuestionsFiltered = Questions.Where(a => a.ShowToA == true).ToList();
        } else
        {
            QuestionsFiltered = Questions.Where(a => a.ShowToB == true).ToList();
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Questions);
```

Please note i have simplified the code here and changed some names, excuse any resulting breakdown in logic.

Comment: Where's the code that doesn't work?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, there can be a question that is marked as `ShowToGroupA` with an answer that is marked as `ShowToGroupB`?

Comment: yes thats right, because the questions and answers are two separate entities. In the future we might decide to show different groups different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter out your response in a new object something like:-

```
List<Questions> Questions = _repo.GetQuestions();
    Questions = Questions.OrderBy(x => x.GroupAOrderNo).ToList();
var  FilteredQuestions =
                Questions.Where(a => GroupAorB == "A" ? a.ShowToGroupA : a.ShowToGroupB).Select(q => new Question
                {
                    ID = q.ID,
                    AllowedResponse =
                        q.AllowedResponse.Where(r => GroupAorB == "A" ? r.ShowToGroupA : r.ShowToGroupB).ToList()

                }).ToList();
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Questions);
```